# https and http, both listening to port 80 on appfog

Tags: php, redirect, https, apache2, port

In my local apache2 server http listens to port 80 and https listens to port 443

But on appfog,

http and https both are listening to port 80 because of which im running into

```
"The webpage has a redirect loop" on google chrome.
```

Any help?

Comment: You can not run HTTPS and HTTP on the same port. Its standard that you use port 443 for HTTPS. When using `http://domain.com` the browser puts :80 behind it, when using `https://domain.com` the browser puts :443 behind it. So just configurate your service to use 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS.

Comment: Look at the chrome console and network tabs for details about what might be causing this.

Comment: I think this is because AppFog puts all servers behind some kind of load balancer, running nginx. On the nginx server stuff like SSL and such are taken care of. Behind it, there are servers running apache, all listening to incoming connections on port 80 from the nginx server. Your .htaccess file is redirecting the requests as seen by the apache server, not the external one. I don't think you can do anything on the apache server to fix this, you would have to edit the nginx configuration, or do something on the client side. I will dig a bit and see if I can find something else.

Answer (score 2):

AppFog puts all of it's Apache servers behind load balancers running on nginx. Internally they are all communicating using default HTTP on port 80, because the gain of encrypting all the communication using SSL in that layer could be discussed. It is possible that they are still using SSL in some way, but that is not important to us. You can't see whether the client uses SSL or not because they are connected to load balancer not your Apache server. Luckily for us nginx sends some additional headers for us. `X-Forwarded-Port` and `X-Forwarded-Proto` to be precise. We could use this to our advantage and check one or more of those fields and redirect accordingly.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !^https$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://yourdomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This solved it for me at least. You might want to do something with `X-Forwarded-Port`, but this should cover most cases.